# Missing syntax-highlighting for x86 assembly

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I know there are not too many [assembly language questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), but still some are and assembly language is an important part of programing (even if the majority of people do not use it).

So I was wondering if it would be possible to add syntax highlight at least for `x86` assembly, like [TASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler) or [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) to make the assembly language questions code more readable.

In case the assembly language syntax highlight is already supported, how do I select it via

`<!-- language: ??? -->`

Markdown code or any other method?

From some quick search of [Stack Overflow Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), which targets *[What is syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)*, I found the supported languages are:

```
"bsh", "c", "cc", "cpp", "cs", "csh",
"cyc", "cv", "htm", "html", "java",
"js", "m", "mxml", "perl", "pl", "pm",
"py", "rb", "sh", "xhtml", "xml", "xsl"
```

so no asm or I overlooked something. For now, I am using `cpp` for `asm` syntax, but that is far from ideal...

By the way, in case it would help my own syntax highlight, tables for `x86` look like this:

```cpp
struct _editor_syntax
    {
    char *keyword[];
    char *bracket[];
    char *operato[];
    char *remblck[];
    char *remline[];
    char *preproc[];
    char *wordspc[];        // Exceptions which would broke syntax highlight rules  (readed word, unreaded postfix)
    };

const _editor_syntax syntax_x86_asm=
    {
    // Pentium iset keywords
    { "AAA","AAD","AAM","AAS","ADC","ADD","AND","ARPL","BOUND","BSF","BSR","BSWAP","BT",
    "BTC","BTR","BTS","CALL","CBW","CDQ","CLC","CLD","CLI","CLTS","CMC","CMOVA","CMOVAE",
    "CMOVB","CMOVBE","CMOVC","CMOVE","CMOVG","CMOVGE","CMOVL","CMOVLE","CMOVNA","CMOVNAE",
    "CMOVNB","CMOVNBE","CMOVNC","CMOVNE","CMOVNG","CMOVNGE","CMOVNL","CMOVNLE","CMOVNO",
    "CMOVNP","CMOVNS","CMOVNZ","CMOVO","CMOVP","CMOVPE","CMOVPO","CMOVS","CMOVZ","CMP",
    "CMPSB","CMPSD","CMPXCHG","CMPXCHG8B","CPUID","CWD","DAA","DAS","DEC","DIV","EMMS",
    "ENTER","F2XM1","FABS","FADD","FADDP","FBLD","FBSTP","FCHS","FCLEX","FCMOVB","FCMOVBE",
    "FCMOVE","FCMOVNB","FCMOVNBE","FCMOVNE","FCMOVNU","FCMOVU","FCOM","FCOMI","FCOMIP",
    "FCOMP","FCOMPP","FCOS","FDECSTP","FDIV","FDIVP","FDIVR","FDIVRP","FFREE","FIADD",
    "FICOM","FICOMP","FIDIV","FIDIVR","FILD","FIMUL","FINCSTP","FINIT","FIST","FISTP",
    "FISUB","FISUBR","FLD","FLD1","FLDCW","FLDENV","FLDL2E","FLDL2T","FLDLG2","FLDLN2",
    "FLDPI","FLDZ","FMUL","FMULP","FNCLEX","FNINIT","FNOP","FNSAVE","FNSTCW","FNSTENV",
    "FNSTSW","FPATAN","FPREM","FPREM1","FPTAN","FRNDINT","FRSTOR","FSAVE","FSCALE","FSIN",
    "FSINCOS","FSQRT","FST","FSTCW","FSTENV","FSTP","FSTSW","FSUB","FSUBP","FSUBR","FSUBRP",
    "FTST","FUCOM","FUCOMI","FUCOMIP","FUCOMP","FUCOMPP","FWAIT","FXAM","FXCH","FXTRACT",
    "FYL2X","FYL2XP1","HLT","IDIV","IMUL","IN","INC","INS","INT","INTO","INVD","INVLPG",
    "IRETD","JA","JAE","JB","JBE","JC","JE","JECXZ","JG","JGE","JL","JLE","JMP","JNE","JNC",
    "JNO","JNS","JNZ","JO","JPE","JPO","JS","LAHF","LAR","LDS","LEA","LEAVE","LES","LFS",
    "LGDT","LGS","LIDT","LLDT","LMSW","LOCK","LODS","LOOP","LOOPE","LOOPNE","LOOPNZ",
    "LOOPZ","LSL","LSS","LTR","MOV","MOVD","MOVQ","MOVS","MOVSX","MOVZX","MUL","NEG",
    "NOP","NOT","OR","OUT","OUTS","PACKSSDW","PACKSSWB","PACKUSWB","PADDB","PADDD",
    "PADDSB","PADDSW","PADDUSB","PADDUSW","PADDW","PAND","PANDN","PCMPEQB","PCMPEQD",
    "PCMPEQW","PCMPGTB","PCMPGTD","PCMPGTW","PMADDWD","PMULHW","PMULLW","POP","POPAD",
    "POPFD","POR","PSLLD","PSLLQ","PSLLW","PSRAD","PSRAW","PSRLD","PSRLQ","PSRLW",
    "PSUBB","PSUBD","PSUBSB","PSUBSW","PSUBUSB","PSUBUSW","PSUBW","PUNPCKHBW","PUNPCKHDQ",
    "PUNPCKHWD","PUNPCKLBW","PUNPCKLDQ","PUNPCKLWD","PUSH","PUSHAD","PUSHFD","PXOR",
    "RCL","RCR","RDMSR","RDPMC","RDTSC","REP","REPE","REPNE","RET","ROL","ROR","RSM",
    "SAHF","SAL","SAR","SBB","SCAS","SETA","SETAE","SETB","SETBE","SETE","SETG","SETGE",
    "SETL","SETLE","SETNE","SETNO","SETNS","SETO","SETPE","SETPO","SETS","SGDT","SHL",
    "SHLD","SHR","SHRD","SIDT","SLDT","SMSW","STC","STD","STI","STOS","STR","SUB","TEST",
    "UD2","VERR","VERW","WAIT","WBINVD","WRMSR","XADD","XCHG","XLAT","XOR",

    "aaa","aad","aam","aas","adc","add","and","arpl","bound","bsf","bsr","bswap","bt",
    "btc","btr","bts","call","cbw","cdq","clc","cld","cli","clts","cmc","cmova","cmovae",
    "cmovb","cmovbe","cmovc","cmove","cmovg","cmovge","cmovl","cmovle","cmovna","cmovnae",
    "cmovnb","cmovnbe","cmovnc","cmovne","cmovng","cmovnge","cmovnl","cmovnle","cmovno",
    "cmovnp","cmovns","cmovnz","cmovo","cmovp","cmovpe","cmovpo","cmovs","cmovz","cmp",
    "cmpsb","cmpsd","cmpxchg","cmpxchg8b","cpuid","cwd","daa","das","dec","div","emms",
    "enter","f2xm1","fabs","fadd","faddp","fbld","fbstp","fchs","fclex","fcmovb","fcmovbe",
    "fcmove","fcmovnb","fcmovnbe","fcmovne","fcmovnu","fcmovu","fcom","fcomi","fcomip",
    "fcomp","fcompp","fcos","fdecstp","fdiv","fdivp","fdivr","fdivrp","ffree","fiadd",
    "ficom","ficomp","fidiv","fidivr","fild","fimul","fincstp","finit","fist","fistp",
    "fisub","fisubr","fld","fld1","fldcw","fldenv","fldl2e","fldl2t","fldlg2","fldln2",
    "fldpi","fldz","fmul","fmulp","fnclex","fninit","fnop","fnsave","fnstcw","fnstenv",
    "fnstsw","fpatan","fprem","fprem1","fptan","frndint","frstor","fsave","fscale","fsin",
    "fsincos","fsqrt","fst","fstcw","fstenv","fstp","fstsw","fsub","fsubp","fsubr","fsubrp",
    "ftst","fucom","fucomi","fucomip","fucomp","fucompp","fwait","fxam","fxch","fxtract",
    "fyl2x","fyl2xp1","hlt","idiv","imul","in","inc","ins","int","into","invd","invlpg",
    "iretd","ja","jae","jb","jbe","jc","je","jecxz","jg","jge","jl","jle","jmp","jne","jnc",
    "jno","jns","jnz","jo","jpe","jpo","js","lahf","lar","lds","lea","leave","les","lfs",
    "lgdt","lgs","lidt","lldt","lmsw","lock","lods","loop","loope","loopne","loopnz",
    "loopz","lsl","lss","ltr","mov","movd","movq","movs","movsx","movzx","mul","neg",
    "nop","not","or","out","outs","packssdw","packsswb","packuswb","paddb","paddd",
    "paddsb","paddsw","paddusb","paddusw","paddw","pand","pandn","pcmpeqb","pcmpeqd",
    "pcmpeqw","pcmpgtb","pcmpgtd","pcmpgtw","pmaddwd","pmulhw","pmullw","pop","popad",
    "popfd","por","pslld","psllq","psllw","psrad","psraw","psrld","psrlq","psrlw",
    "psubb","psubd","psubsb","psubsw","psubusb","psubusw","psubw","punpckhbw","punpckhdq",
    "punpckhwd","punpcklbw","punpckldq","punpcklwd","push","pushad","pushfd","pxor",
    "rcl","rcr","rdmsr","rdpmc","rdtsc","rep","repe","repne","ret","rol","ror","rsm",
    "sahf","sal","sar","sbb","scas","seta","setae","setb","setbe","sete","setg","setge",
    "setl","setle","setne","setno","setns","seto","setpe","setpo","sets","sgdt","shl",
    "shld","shr","shrd","sidt","sldt","smsw","stc","std","sti","stos","str","sub","test",
    "ud2","verr","verw","wait","wbinvd","wrmsr","xadd","xchg","xlat","xor",    },
    // brackets
    { "(",")","[","]","PUSH","POP","PUSHA","POPA","PUSHAD","POPAD","PUSHFD","POPFD","push","pop","pusha","popa","pushad","popad","pushfd","popfd","" },
    };
```

Which provides simple highlight (which is often enough) like this:

[image: Highlight example]

For code taken from this Q&A:

- *[What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572266/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-an-object-on-the-screen/29579522#29579522)*

My narrow-sight experience/observation is that `asm` questions are often asked by rookies and syntax highlight is much more important for them than for seasoned programmers...

**[Edit 1]**

As suggested, I added a new issue for assembly language support:

- [code-prettify issue #483](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/483)

Comment: *"asm question is often asked by rookies"* this seems wonderfully contradictory to me. I would expect asm questions to be asked by war-hardened veterans of the community!

Comment: @Gimby me too but all the asm questions I saw here on SO was asked by rookies ... possibly due to the combination of search TAGs I use

Comment: You'll need to take this up with the prettify project, see the FAQ I duped you to (the *How do I report a bug or request a new language?* section).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added new issue as suggested (hopefully at the right place with enough info)... added link to it as edit1

Comment: Even though I somehow missed this Meta question, [I submitted a pull request for this several months ago](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/486). Still awaiting feedback from the project's maintainers. Once we get that, we'll still need to bother the SO team to pull the latest revision of Prettify.

Comment: @CodyGray +1 for that ... If things change please let me know so I can update language settings on some of my answers ...