# Code highlighting for Assembly

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Is there code highlighting for Assembly?

I read some posts but none of them seems to provide a solution:

[Missing syntax-highlighting for x86 assembly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348110/6865932)

Comment: @rene, I've tried several languages, but to no avail, using `;` makes a comment in `asm` and AFAICT there is no other languange that does the same. Thanks.

Comment: I checked the current highlight.js in use by SE and that doesn't contain a registerLanguage call for  "asm' or its variants. The best you can do is wait for Highlight.js to come to Stack Overflow and then have assembler added to the language set. https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/  see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1#comment1183352_354029

Comment: @rene, yes, for now adding `//` to the code will have to do.

Comment: Related [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354368/369403) on the thread about syntax highlighting.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I've decided to close this as a duplicate of a *newer* question. I did so because that newer question (A) has more votes than this one, and (B) offers a bit more fleshed-out justification for why the action should be taken. If you're really offended by this, I suppose you can ping me and I'll reverse the direction of the duplicate marking.

Comment: @Cody no problem, I agree with your reasoning.